# Magento2 install integration test db, throws error for module even though module is disabled

Tags: integration-testing, magento2

I'm trying to run the Magento2 integration tests which, as we know, install a stripped down database to test against. The first time I ran it I got the following exception that a plugin was trying to wrap round a category save and launch some indexing and throwing an exception on failure.

```
 Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}() at /app/vendor/algolia/algoliasearch-magento-2/Model/Indexer/CategoryObserver.php:32
 Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Model\Indexer\CategoryObserver->aroundSave() at /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php:67
```

Fair enough - they haven't considered the integration tests when they coded... So... I know what... I'll disable the module from the command line! Brilliant...

```
php bin/magento module:disable Algolia_AlgoliaSearch
```

Now here is the weird bit - run the integration tests again - same error...

So here are my questions:

1. Do disabled modules still install (given the above presumably so).
2. How do I stop the module interfering with the installation of the integration Database without de-installing the module (which would be a blinking nuisance, just to install the integration db.)

Comment: It seems that integration tests simply enable all modules, no matter what. Not sure if this is a bug or a feature :-/

Comment: if failing the integration tests banned you from being accepted into the Marketplace I'd say that it was a feature, with the assumption that all official modules should be able to be enabled without breaking the integration DB - but if you are allowed to be in Marketplace even if your module fails integration tests then its a bug...  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The Marketplace has nothing to do with this. I'm using integration tests for our custom modules and to run automated tests for every deployment we do. I never had this problem before, but since M2.2.4, the `Vertex_Tax`-module seems to add a new (required) field to the customer model, which breaks certain integration tests that are creating customers.

Comment: I was simply commenting on your question of bug vs feature... a hint to the way the core team think would be if their behaviour was consistent... enforcing the passing of tests as an acceptance criteria to Marketplace would be consistent with it being a feature, inconsistency would hint to it being a bug deserving of a bug report at [Github/magento2](https://github.com/magento/magento2)

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it... I've written a patch that puts a `try {} catch (\Exception $e) {};` block around the offending call...

Simple really - though it does mean touching code I don't own... I'd still be interested in a more elegant solution?